# java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout android 5.1.1

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, ioexception

I was trying to connect my phone to bluetooth module HC-05 embedded within arduino. But I see, Its throwing a weird Exception. Can someone please brief me why am i facing this problem and if possible, how can i fix this ?
Here is my code...

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("98:D3:33:80:67:F2");
                ConnectThread connectThread =new ConnectThread(bluetoothDevice);
                connectThread.start();
            }
        });
    }


    class ConnectThread extends Thread{

        BluetoothSocket mmBluetoothSocket;
        BluetoothDevice mmBLuetoothDevice;
        private final UUID myuuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice){
            mmBLuetoothDevice = bluetoothDevice;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            try {
                tmp =  mmBLuetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myuuid);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mmBluetoothSocket = tmp;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mmBluetoothSocket.connect();  //java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout,
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mmBluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        }


        public void cancel()  {
            try {
                mmBluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing this exception `java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout.` I have never faced this exception Before.

Comment: What do you mean by before ? Because this error says that the device is unreachable meaning either turned off, out of range, or the service UUID is incorrect.

Comment: @Mackovich The Device is not turned off and its in the range as well. Maybe its because of UUID. How do we get the correct UUID ? I Just took it randomly from the Internet.

Comment: The UUID is most important ! To explain things the simplest way, your targetted Bluetooth device has a Bluetooth chip. Each applications/services that run on this device must have registered itself to this chip with a specific Bluetooth protocol and in our case, a specific UUID ! Now, if you don't have a documentation that specifies which are these UUIDs and what services they correspond to, you have to use `BluetoothDevice.getUuids()`. Parse the result and post here all UUIDs you get, here ;-) I'll help you more after.

Comment: It raised nullpointerException. I did the following `StringBuilder stringbuilder = null;
                    while ((bt = bluetoothDevice.getUuids())!= null){
                        stringbuilder.append(Arrays.toString(bt));
                    }
                    String uuidString = stringbuilder.toString();
                    Log.wtf("UUID",uuidString);`

Comment: Well of course you get a `NullPointerException` ! You initiliazed your **Stringbuilder** to null and not `new StringBuilder()` ! Try something like this : http://pastebin.com/Q6KMSwew and also why do you use `Log.wtf`? It's for very very serious error ;-) Check the documentation!

Comment: yea, there is a little indifference for that `wtf` method. BTW, It Still returns a null. Here is my approach http://pastebin.com/2DVWcs48 ... please correct me if I have done anything wrong.

Comment: Can you post de error log stack trace of this `NullPointerException`?

Comment: `01-15 16:50:43.706  13837-13837/com.example.milind.hc_05 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.milind.hc_05, PID: 13837
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
            at com.example.milind.hc_05.MainActivity$ConnectThread.<init>(MainActivity.java:44)
            at com.example.milind.hc_05.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)` Line number 29 is that line where I have Instantiated the ConnectThread class

Comment: hmm I think the variable you pass to your ConnectThread constructor is **null** !! Apparently, if the line number is the same in your pastebin, `bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("98:D3:33:80:67:F2");` returns `null` that's why you get a **NullPointerException** at `bluetoothDevice.getUuids()`

Comment: What Does that Mean ? I am Having HC-05.

Comment: it means you application fails to build a proper BluetoothDevice from that mac adress. Use the debugger set a break point and see what happen : I believe your BluetoothDevice is null :/

Comment: Can you please Elaborate on that point ?

Comment: have you ever use Android Studio debugger ? If not : http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html It will help you see what's wrong and if `bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("98:D3:33:80:67:F2");` returns **null**. If it does it means that your `HC-05` is not paired with you device.